# ObjectLoader asset not playing animations

Tags: animation, three.js, hierarchy, scene

I have been using the single mesh export method on animated models, loading it with the JSONLoader (using this tutorial http://unboring.net/workflows/animation.html ) and it works fine.

For scenes with more than just 1 mesh I export the full scene (Scene and Hierarchy selected) and use the ObjectLoader. So far it works fine, i can add them to the threeScene and render everything fine, no problem.

However when i want to do the same with the model from the tutorial above (export as full scene) i cant animate the character. I can do the whole same procedure i do with the asset loaded with the JsonLoader, i can even get the mixer's 'loop' and 'finished' dispatched events from an animation being played but the model never moves, it stays on the T-pose. Internally it seems its working fine, but the character doesnt do anything. Im basically running the same code for both types of character loading, except no animation is shown.

Should i be doing an extra check somewhere? i also tried cloning the geometry from the ObjectLoader result but it didnt clone the animations so i guess that doesnt works either.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like even as skinning is checked true on the blender export, i still had to set to true on skinning on the code.

```js
            clonedObject3d.material.skinning = true;
```